# How to get value from JSON with dynamic key in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

The following query gets all key names that are needed from a `jsonb` object. Basically, getting all key names that contain 'foo' from a column called 'objects'.

```
SELECT keys
FROM (
    SELECT jsonb_object_keys(objects) as keys
    from table
) as testvalues
WHERE keys LIKE '%foo%';
```

Once I get the set of key names, I want to access the `status` field of that object as follows

```
SELECT objects->'hello_foo'->'status' FROM table
```

However, I still can't find a way to go through the set of key names in the first query and dynamically access the `status` field.

What would be the best implementation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `jsonb_each()` to extract all elements as key/value pairs. Then you can filter by the `key`s and access the `value` objects:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1a3c2116ea7e0d70a88085b6e539772d)

```
SELECT
    *,
    objects.value -> 'status'
FROM
    t,
    jsonb_each(mydata) objects
WHERE objects.key::text LIKE '%foo%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use funciton `jsonb_extract_path`.

For example, if you have table `my_json_data`, whihc has fields `row_id` and `json_data`, then you can use query below:

```
SELECT jsonb_extract_path(json_data, 'pathName') AS my_value
FROM my_json_data WHERE row_id = 100;
```

You can replace `'pathName'` with variable etc.